# Why is camera_info typically a topic?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, camera-info

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the camera extrinsics/intrinsics are usually fixed parameters, why is there usually a camera_info topic for cameras instead of having the extrinsics/intrinsics be in a parameter server?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403708/why-is-camera_info-typically-a-topic?/) by [yukaryote](https://answers.ros.org/users/110456/yukaryote/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2022-07-12

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're right that in virtually all cases, the camera extrinsics/intrinsics don't change. There only exception that I've encountered is when you're calibrating a camera and committing the calibration, the camera_info gets updated.

However, apart from that, using parameters would be much more cumbersome than using a topic: If you were using a set of parameters, you would need some way of telling the subscribers to an image topic where to look up the corresponding camera info parameters. The only way that I can think of would be a topic where the path to the parameters is published. At that point, it's much better to just publish the full camera_info on that topic. With the camera_info topic, you can use all of ROS's built-in features like topic remapping to get the info to the subscriber.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2022-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3